# Batch File Command - Remove Lines With Phrases From File

Tags: regex, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to cut out unnecessary lines from a list of installed programs on devices.

Currently using:

```
type "original.txt" | findstr /v "Click-to-Run" | findstr /v "Visual C++" | findstr /v "Windows*SDK*"  > "example_new.txt"
```

I need it to remove lines such as "Windows Desktop SDK Tools" but KEEP lines such as ".Net Framework 4.0.0 SDK".

How can I get this to only remove the lines that contain the entire phrases specified?
Is it possible to do that, while also using wildcard in the phrases?

Thanks so much!

Comment: findstr has a small subset of REGEX (enough to do what you want). The [documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) should fully answer your question.

Comment: findstr /v /C:"Windows.*SDK" does not work for me. I assume since I am declaring a literal? Sorry am new to this. Need this to include entire phrase but also with a wildcard of any or no characters in between. I saw using .* instead of * , but does not work.

Comment: Found it! Thank you! I needed: findstr /V /R /C:"Windows.*SDK"

Answer (score 2):

You can make your life easier (especially if your list is long) by using the `/g` switch (see `findstr /?` for details).

```
type "original.txt" | findstr /vrg:"exclude.txt" > "example_new.txt"
```

with `exclude.txt` containing your "to-ignore" list (REGEX allowed):

```
Click-to-Run
Visual C++
Windows.*SDK
```

(the `/g` includes `/c`, so spaces are no problem)